# Evaluate $\frac{1}{\tau} \int\limits_0^\tau{{(e^{\alpha t}-1)e^{-\beta t}}}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

I have to evaluate $\frac{1}{\tau} \int\limits_0^\tau{{(e^{\alpha t}-1)e^{-\beta t}}}dt$ , where ατ=1.

I did he following:

[image]

But they have the following answer:

[image]

Have I forgotten something? I did it multiple times. Can't get nearer to their result.

I apologize for not posting everything at once.

Comment: How's the editing going?

Comment: I can't cope with it. Can't understand why I couldn't write everything as I did with the title.

Comment: According to Wolfram, the given answer is way wrong...

Comment: It seems to me that your answer is correct. But you need to replace $\alpha$ with $1/\tau$.